# Running successive sets of animations in tkinter with break in between

Tags: python-3.x, animation, tkinter

[Graphic Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AFZ1.png)

Hi, my first post here! I am a first time coder trying to figure out an issue. Any help is deeply appreciated.

I'm trying to create an "animation" by changing background colors ("blink") of four Labels. So the idea is for it to blink a couple times in a sequence, then pause to a take user input. This animation-user input cycle is repeated a couple times.

I've attempted to use the after method to do this. But instead of animating sequentially, everything gets clubbed together and runs together, at the end. In other words, if I try to do successive animation, the first time animation doesn't get executed before moving onto the next animation

#### this section is where the animation sequence is generated.

```
    self.genRandom(3)  # generate random sequence of numbers
    self.createSchedule(3) #relate the random sequence onto image on screen
    self.doanim() #execute animation 


    self.delay=10000  #delay before beginning next animation 
    self.after(self.delay, self.genRandom(3))
    self.after(self.delay, self.createSchedule(3))
    self.after(self.delay, self.doanim())
```

### schedule generation (relating sequence number to images) (delay,label color change function)

```
def createSchedule(self,seqn):
    self.schedule.clear()
    tuple=(2000, self.labelbegin)
    self.schedule.append(tuple)
    #     (10, lambda: self.associateDigLogo())
    for number in self.listSeqn:
        #     (10, lambda: self.associateDigLogo()
        if number == 0:
            self.schedule.extend(((1000,lambda: self.buttonpresswhatsapp(None)), (500, lambda: self.buttonreleasewhatsapp(None))))
        elif number == 1:
            self.schedule.extend(((1000, lambda: self.buttonpressslack(None)), (500, lambda: self.buttonreleaseslack(None))))
        elif number == 2:
            self.schedule.extend(((1000, lambda: self.buttonpressskype(None)), (500, lambda: self.buttonreleaseskype(None))))
        elif number ==3:
            self.schedule.extend(((1000, lambda: self.buttonpresssnapchat(None)), (500, lambda: self.buttonreleasesnapchat(None))))
```

### this section is where the animation is executed

```
def doanim(self):

    if len(self.schedule) <= 0:
        return
    self.sched_item = 0

    s = self.schedule[self.sched_item]
    #run the function stored in the schedule
    print(s[0])
    self.after(s[0], self.doanim_helper)


def doanim_helper(self):

    s = self.schedule[self.sched_item]
    # run the function stored in the schedule
    s[1]()

    self.sched_item += 1
    print(self.sched_item)

    if self.sched_item >= len(self.schedule):
        self.after(1000, self.quit)
    else:
        s = self.schedule[self.sched_item]
        self.after(s[0], self.doanim_helper)
```

### sample of graphic functions called above

```
def buttonpresswhatsapp(self, event):
    self.whatsapplabel.config(bg="red")

def buttonreleasewhatsapp(self, event):
    self.whatsapplabel.config(bg="white")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), when a function is passed arguments,

> All argument expressions are evaluated before the call is attempted

Therefore, in `self.after(self.delay, self.genRandom(3))`, the function call `self.genRandom(3)` is evaluated *immediately*, then its return value is passed to `self.after`. This is why "everything gets clubbed together", lacking the expected delay.

Instead, you want to pass a callable (e.g. function object) as the second argument:

```
self.after(self.delay, lambda: self.genRandom(3))
self.after(self.delay, lambda: self.createSchedule(3))
self.after(self.delay, self.doanim)
```

---

`self.genRandom` is a function. Functions are first-class objects which can be passed as arguments to other functions. In Python, parentheses after a function cause the function to be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! I tried your code (with lambda even for self.doanim) but then the animation sequence runs only for the first time and the code ends without executing the 2nd one. Not even the sequence numbers are recalculated. Its better than before but this is an new problem